# Is it possible to identify from the user-agent if a Huawei device is NOT supporting google services?

Tags: google-analytics, user-agent, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I would like to check in my Google Analytics how big a proportion of my user base is using Huawei devices which are no longer using google services but instead using App Gallery etc.

I was wondering if I could e.g. look for specific OS versions in the User-Agents etc.?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you are looking for ways to detect Huawei devices that are not Google supported, meaning Huawei devices without Google Mobile Services (aka Google Play Services, or GMS).

To detect these particular devices, you need to first obtain Huawei device model number list released after May 2019, these generally include Mate 30, 40, P40 series. You can get the list from [here](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei-phones-58.php) (sort by Time of release).

Get Huawei device model through the following methods, then check it against the non-GMS Huawei device list that you have built.

- Android app – Implement Firebase Analytics to detect and report device model. You can also try [Huawei Analytics Kit](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/introduction-0000001050745149-V5).
- Web host (since you mentioned ‘user-agent’) – Huawei device browsers report HMS and device model number in user-agent header and your web host can pick it up. Here is an example of user-agent reported by Huawei Mate 30 Pro (model # **LIO-AL00**):

  a.   Huawei Browser – Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; **LIO-AL00**; HMSCore
  5.0.4.301) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 HuaweiBrowser/11.0.4.300 Mobile Safari/537.36

  b.   Google Chrome – Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; **LIO-AL00**)
  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.114 Mobile
  Safari/537.36

If you just need to determine if certain devices don’t have Google Play Services, you can make use of this [API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)):

**public int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable ([Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) context)**

Verifies that Google Play services is installed and enabled on this device, and that the version installed on this device is no older than the one required by this client.

**Returns**

•   status code indicating whether there was an error. Can be one of following in [ConnectionResult](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult): SUCCESS, SERVICE_MISSING, SERVICE_UPDATING, SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, SERVICE_DISABLED, SERVICE_INVALID

If the result is SERVICE_MISSING, then create a custom event in Firebase Analytics and report it with device model. This is a sure way to determine if the device has not Google Play Services.

Comment: For Browser, use JavaScript `navigator.userAgent` to get the above mentioned information.

Answer (score 0):

The user agent is not shown in Google Analytics but the information deriving from it is shown, for example the type of device, its category of device, the browser used, its version, etc ...

Hete you can find list of all Dimensions and Metrics available: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/dimensions-metrics-explorer/

Comment: Thanks, I kind of knew that, the question is more about the identifiers that I would look for, for Huawei devices which are NOT google supported...?

Answer (score 0):

According to @Michele Pisani, the Google Analytics Core Reporting API can give you access to most of the report data in Google Analytics.

According to [this documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012034?hl=en), you can get the device info from Google Analytics - Audience reports - Mobile (Devices).

Also, if you integrate HUAWEI Analytics Kit, you can filter users of different brands, device models, and regions in the **Filter** area of Huawei Analysis Reports for detailed analysis and comparison analysis.

For example, you can compare the new user trend of different device brands in a period of time.

Select the filter criteria in (1) and add comparison analysis conditions in (2). Then, you can view the comparison trends in the new user trend chart in (3) and the comparison values in the table in (4). You can download the data for personalized analysis. In (5), click VS to clear the comparison conditions.

[image: analysis]

Comment: Yes thanks, I know I can get device info etc. from GA. My question is more about the identifiers that I would look for, for Huawei devices which are NOT google supported...?